# Date validation in Formik: 'Date of purchase' must be earlier than 'Date of sale'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I am creating a simple form with date validation in React, Formik and Yup.

As you can see below, there are only two fields: `datePurchase` and `dateSale`. I set `min` and `max` parameters for both and I set them as required:

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    datePurchase: '',
    dateSale: '',
  }}
  validationSchema={object()
    .shape({
      datePurchase: date()
        .min(new Date('01-01-2019'))
        .max(new Date())
        .required(),
      dateSale: date()
        .min(new Date('01-01-2019'))
        .max(new Date())
        .required(),
    })}
>
  {({
    values, handleChange, handleBlur,
  }) => (
      <Form>
        <input
          name="datePurchase"
          type="date"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.datePurchase}
        />
        <input
          name="dateSale"
          type="date"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          value={values.dateSale}
        />
      </Form>
    )}
</Formik>
```

Then, I realized that `datePurchase` must be earlier than `dateSale`.

How to implement such condition using `validationSchema()` with Yup? Is that even possible?

I tried to use `when()` method with `is:` and `then:` params from Yup documentation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yup.ref allows you to reference other siblings - https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuprefpath-string-options--contextprefix-string--ref

Try giving this a go:

```
validationSchema={object()
    .shape({
      datePurchase: date()
        .min(Yup.ref('dateSale')
        .max(new Date())
        .required(),
      dateSale: date()
        .min(new Date('01-01-2019'))
        .max(new Date())
        .required(),
    })}
```

Comment: Maybe, I should have written `Date of sale` must be **later** than `Date of purchase`, because the user sets `datePurchase` first. So, I have changed the order to: `datePurchase: date().min(new Date('01-01-2019')).max(new Date())` and `dateSale: date().min(ref('datePurchase')).max(new Date())`. Thank you! It works great!

Comment: Haha, glad it worked! I did think that it was a strange order for you to specify :P